# VBA Copy & Paste multiple sources (Odd code behaviour)

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to write some VBA code to open several workbooks, copy a column, and past into the book I run the macro from. I need the data I copy over to all go into the same column. Here is my code:

```
Sub MeToo_Paste()
'Assign Report Book
Dim x As Workbook
'Assign Source Books
Dim y As Workbook
Dim z As Workbook
'Open Report Book
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Filepath\Documents\Report.xlsm")
'Open Source Books
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Filepath\Documents\Source 1.xlsx")
Set z = Workbooks.Open("C:\Filepath\Documents\Source 2.xlsx")
'Copy & Paste 1
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B500").Copy
x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").PasteSpecial
'Copy & Paste 2
z.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B500").Copy
x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
'Close
y.Close
z.Close
End Sub
```

My first question is about the behaviour of this code. It only works correctly if none of my sourcebooks are open when I run the macro. If anything else is open when code is run, copying & pasting doesn't happen in the books I specify. It seems to paste into the most recent book that I opened manually.

I don't understand why this could happen, as I set my report book to 'x' and the only pasting code should be on 'x'.

My second question is about making this code more elegant. I would rather not use the clipboard and instead set the data I want to copy as a variable, so I would use the following code instead;

```
Dim Info As Variant
Info = y.sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
x.sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = Info
```

However using this method, I don't know how to select the range I want when it comes to transferring from the second source book. As I need the data to all be in one column, I need a way to change ("B2") to whatever the next empty cell is in that column.

Comment: You need to test whether the file is open or not first.  Read this from Microsoft https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the 2nd part of your question:

```
    Dim rowcount As Long
    Dim Info As Variant
    Info = y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value

    rowcount = x.Cells(x.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & rowount).Value = Info
```

Comment: When stepping through my code with this included, I get a debug error of 'Object doesn't support this property or method' concerning the rowcount = x.cells... line.

Comment: You would need `x.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`.  I would suggest that you do the following to limit the lengthiness, `Dim ws1 as Worksheet`, then `Set ws1 = x.Sheets("Sheet1")` then you can just use `ws1.Cells...`